# Is there a way (or software) to sync reading a pdf across machines

Tags: pdf, sync, cloud

I have a pdf in my dropbox and would like to continue reading on the page I last left.  I would like this to happen regardless of whatever machine I am using.

Is there a good way to do this?  Is there a pdf reader out there where I can keep an .ini file or something in the same directory as the pdf and keep both in dropbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way for anyone interested (this only works across multiple PCs only):

1. Download a portable pdf reader and install to a dropbox folder (this is where the ini file gets tracked.).
2. Create the same folder on each PC with ebooks inside (C:\MyEbooks)